# twilio screen shot android

Tags: android, screenshot, twilio, twilio-api

I am implementing **Twilio Video calling API** and according to my use-case, I need to take **screenshot** while the call is going. I tried traditional screenshot methods of android but it's showing **black screen** for the streaming.

[This is the black screenshot coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F3RB.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Sachin